# How to set value of variable in "BeginInvoke" delegate function in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, begininvoke

I have this code on different thread:

```
string sub = "";

this.BeginInvoke((Action)(delegate()
{
    try
    {
        sub = LISTVIEW.Items[x].Text.Trim();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}));

MessageBox.Show(sub);
```

what I want is to get the value of "`LISTVIEW.Items[x].Text.Trim();`" and pass it to "sub". please note that the LISTVIEW control is on the main thread. now how can I accomplish this?

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Func<string> foo = () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return LISTVIEW.Items[x].Text.Trim();
                }
                catch
                {
                     // this is the diaper anti-pattern... fix it by adding logging and/or making the code in the try block not throw
                     return String.Empty;

                }
            };

        var ar = this.BeginInvoke(foo);

        string sub = (string)this.EndInvoke(ar);
```

You, of course, need to be a bit careful with EndInvoke because it can cause deadlocks.

if you prefer delegate syntax you can also change

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(delegate()
```

to

```
this.BeginInvoke((Func<String>)(delegate()
```

you stll need to return something from all branches and call end invoke.

Comment: lambda syntax is just a nicer way to create a delegate. So its still a delegate.

Comment: @ermac2014 You can. This is a little bit of a red-herring. The important thing to note that the code in BeginInvoke is *asynchronous wrt. the caller*. Setting the variable as in the post (with the appropriate thread visibility control) would work ... but it would only be *guaranteed* after the EndInvoke. From [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx): "Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on."

Comment: thanks for the solutions and explanations. its working like charm :)

Comment: If you're going to BeginInvoke, EndInvoke, you might as well simply change the original code to use Invoke.